# How to fix unsatisfiedLinkError Couldn't find dso to load in WhatsApp Sticker App

Tags: java, android

I created a WhatsApp Sticker App from the resources from official GitHub and now have some issues with installing it from Google Play.

I modified the code from there, cleaned it all up, and it worked fine if you installed it from Google Play or Android Studio.
A few days ago I added some new stickers and I tried to install it first with Android Studio to look if there are some errors. All worked fine so I published it on Google play. Now it crashes when you install it from Google Play.
I googled and found some things but nothing helped ( https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d)

I have no idea why this happens only by installing it from Google play
The crash says something that there is a missing library.

Here is the full source code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WR0ch7wjftfXcEQy_acBeKCBoqNfXga8

And the errors from the Google Dev Console and Android Studios logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:365)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:257)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.b (Unknown Source:254)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source:106)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source:94)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source:1)
  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.d.a (Unknown Source:20)
  at com.facebook.animated.webp.WebPImage.a (Unknown Source)
  at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.a (Unknown Source:17)
  at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.a (Unknown Source:19)
  at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.a (Unknown Source:155)
  at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.c.a (Unknown Source:109)
  at de.anteiku.ministickers.activities.EntryActivity$a.a (Unknown Source:11)
  at de.anteiku.ministickers.activities.EntryActivity$a.doInBackground (Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
```

```
2019-02-02 23:57:16.304 4428-4452/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: de.anteiku.ministickers, PID: 4428
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:365)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libstatic-webp.so
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.b(Unknown Source:254)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source:106)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source:94)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.b.a(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.facebook.animated.webp.WebPImage.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.a(Unknown Source:17)
        at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.a(Unknown Source:19)
        at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.a(Unknown Source:155)
        at de.anteiku.ministickers.b.c.a(Unknown Source:109)
        at de.anteiku.ministickers.activities.EntryActivity$a.a(Unknown Source:11)
        at de.anteiku.ministickers.activities.EntryActivity$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)�
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)�
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)�
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)�
```

Comment: You are getting this error because the package that contains `libstatic-webp.so` is not either not being installed, or it is being installed in the wrong place. This is what an unsatisfiedlinkerror means

Comment: then explain me please why i can install it without any issues from Android Studio?

Comment: do you get any solution of this error? Please share your solution

Comment: @AnandSavjani I don't have a real solution to this error
Setting the project up new again and transfering my stuff fixed it...
But sometimes I got this error again and I gave up searching for a real solution

Comment: @Toπ please raise this issue on Github or on Facebook because no one has solution of this big issue.

Comment: @AnandSavjani I think you can do this on your own(I stoped making my Sticker App)

Comment: @Toπ I have raised issue but no any update from facebook